# How to pass state from parent to child as props then from that child to it s child as props in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

For now everything is static data .

**I have a parent sate: an array containing 4 objects
like so :**

```
 function App(){

  const [searchResults,setSearchResults] = 
    useState([
      {
      name: 'name1',
      artist: 'artist1',
      album: 'album1',
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'name2',
      artist: 'artist2',
      album: 'album2',
      id: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'name3',
      artist: 'artist3',
      album: 'album3',
      id: 3
    },
    {
      name: 'name4',
      artist: 'artist4',
      album: 'album4',
      id: 4
    }
  ]);
```

**i pass this state to the child  in the return with this it works as expected :**

```
return (
 <SearchResults searchResults = {searchResults} />
)
```

**and from  i pass it to :**

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import './SearchResults.css';
import TrackList from '../TrackList/TrackList';


export default function SearchResults({searchResults}) {
    return (
        <div className="SearchResults">
            <h2>Results</h2>
             <TrackList tracks = {searchResults} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

now is where things got me confused.

**i try to map the data from the array to the child of this component like this(this is the whole component) :**

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import './TrackList.css';
import Track from '../Track/Track'

export default function TrackList(props) {
    return(
        <div className="TrackList">
            {
                props.tracks.map( track => {
                    <Track track = {track} key = {track.id} />
                })
            }
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

**and i get this error with the local server displaying a white screen**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5niRQ.png

- i tried destructuring and assigning props value to a variable before mapping but didn't work .
- also when i remove the .map i can see that  has a props with expected data in it using react dev tools .

Comment: Could you share where you use the componenet TrackList.

Comment: You are'nt sending tracks in props. In function, use console.log(props) or debugging, to see your props. You will already see tracks is not in your props. If SearchResults component is the TrackList, your searchResults is the prop you sent. So try to use it. Also, If you give the same name in each exported component for the same page, it becomes easier for you.

Comment: i just edited the post i skipped a step i posted the <SearchResults /> components where <TrackList/> is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not in the components that you have mentioned, it is in the `Playlist` component, wherein you have loaded the `TrackList` component without the `tracks` prop. Please accept the answer if it helps your case. Thank you!

Comment: yes that s it ! it solved the errors . how do i accept the answer ?

Comment: Tick on the arrow below, thanks! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You always can view what you transfer to props with console.

```
console.log(props);
```

You need add `console.log(props);` before return statement, like this

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import './TrackList.css';
import Track from '../Track/Track'

export default function TrackList(props) {

console.log(props);
    return(
        <div className="TrackList">
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: where can i check what the console logs ?

Comment: You may meet with `dev tools` your browser . For simple open console in browser press _F12_ and select tab _Console_.

Comment: the props value is indeed passed to <TrackList /> but i can only confirm it once i remove the  {tracks.map} from it s return . once i added the whole app is blank and i can t interact with or check anything

Comment: You need add `console.log(props);` before return statement, I change answer, view new version and try this.

Comment: i added it like you said and it actually logged twice fisrt one it got all the expected date and second it s an empty array

Answer (score 0):

you need pass props to SearchResults component not a param

like this

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import './SearchResults.css';
import TrackList from '../TrackList/TrackList';


export default function SearchResults(props) {
  return (
    <div className="SearchResults">
        <h2>Results</h2>
         <TrackList tracks = {props.searchResults} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: the result is the same as i used destructuring there to save me some keystrokes. i just tried it again with same result

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your code in a sandbox, but I have excluded the `Tracks` component. I don't see any bug, please refer to it and let me know if you need any more help. Also, when using `map` or any other function you need to either use the `return` keyword or avoid using the curly braces `{}`.

For example, inside `TrackList` function:

```
{
     props.tracks.map( track => { //here avoid this or use 'return' keyword inside
          <Track track = {track} key = {track.id} />
     })
}

//Like this:
{
     props.tracks.map( track => 
          <Track track = {track} key = {track.id} />
     )
}

//or
{
     props.tracks.map( track => 
          { return <Track track = {track} key = {track.id} /> }
     )
}
```

[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-northcutt-yonxy3?file=/src/TrackList.js)